# Reading a csv file with text content

Tags: r

I have a csv file with data like this

```
firstcolumn secondcolumn
text1       freetext 1
text2       freetext 2
```

When I read the csv file I use this:

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/testfile.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Is there any parameter I should include in order to have every line of the second column as chr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming, when you do read.csv, the second column will be of the type factors.

You can do this to cross check:

```
class(df$secondcolumn)
```

Now, if you want to convert them to characters, I can think of two ways. The first one does not work for me always, but the second one does.

**First one:**
stringsAsFactors needs to be set to false FALSE

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/testfile.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**Second one:**
If the first method does not work, then you do this manually by setting the particular column to characters

```
df$secondcolumn <- as.character(df$secondcolumn)
```

Comment: Yes it is the type factors

Comment: Then please try the two things I have suggested

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the import wizard in RStudio?  You can specify all the formats there, and have the wizard generate the code.

[image: Location of Import Wizard RStudio]